# what is the error in the itemclicked?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlistwidget

i have a python that includes a list that handle the path of existing PDF FILES in the selected folder.

what i want is to make the system print in the console the selected item when the user click on the item.

so it must be connect to an **itemclick event**.

i will appreciate any help.

the system display this exception :

**this error occure 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'**

this  is how i tried to make it :
     **self.listWidgetPDFlist.itemClicked....** how to continue?

create an empty list

```
fileList=[]
```

loop over the selected folder and add the matched item to the **widgetList**

```
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):
            for filename in files:
                if filename.endswith('.pdf'):
                    t=os.path.join(directory,filename)
                    print(t)
                    #fileList.extend(t)
                    fileList.append(t)

        # add the list into the  listWidgetPDFlist          
        self.listWidgetPDFlist.addItems(fileList)
```

upon selection of an item  make the system print in the console the current item

```
self.listWidgetPDFlist.itemClicked(print(self.listWidgetPDFlist.currentItem().text()))
```

the problem is in the above line of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Item clicked is a signal and must be connected to function.

```
self.listWidgetPDFlist.itemClicked.connect(lambda: print(self.listWidgetPDFlist.currentItem().text()))
```

The line above uses a lambda statement to print the selected item in a single line of code. This will work for very simple things like you are trying to do here, but you can also connect this to a method to do more.

```
    self.listWidgetPDFlist.itemClicked.connect(self.print_item)

def print_item(self):
    print(self.listWidgetPDFlist.currentItem().text())
    # handle other items here
```

When connecting to a method you must leave the parentheses off the methods name when connecting it to the signal.

Comment: your answer work perfect ..... but i tried to add  a code that add the selected item to a new list  but did not work  it display these error **File "C:\Users\test\Documents\Python_Projects\final_project\myPDFviewer.py", line 126, in <module>
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
File "C:\Users\test\Documents\Python_Projects\final_project\myPDFviewer.py", line 36, in print_item
  self.listWidgetPDFlist.currentItem(self.listWidget.addItem())
builtins.TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
addItem(self, QListWidgetItem): not enough arguments
addItem(self, str): not enough arguments**

Comment: It seems like you are having trouble with how to use PyQt functions.  You are supplying an argument to a method that does not take one, and not supplying an argument to a method that needs one.  I think what you may be looking for here is: `self.listWidget.addItem(self.listWidgetPDFlist.currentItem().text())`

Comment: thank you for your help .

can you help me with a different problem ?
i am trying to highlight text  using python but nothing is working  yet